# Android: Draw a scalable rectangle(Should change colours on my input)around a bitmap

Tags: android

Can anybody help me to draw a scalable rectangle around a bitmap
    And such that 1) The rectangle should scale based on the size of my bitmap
                  2) The colour of my rectangle should change on my input
    any help would be appreciated
    Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create class extending View, and override onDraw and onTouchEvent methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
DashPathEffect dashPath =new DashPathEffect(new float[ ]{70,2}, 30);
paint.setPathEffect(dashPath);
paint.setStrokeWidth(80);
canvas.drawLine(30, 300 , 320, 300, paint);
```